# How to parse an input string and print it in canonicalized? (Java)

Tags: java

I need a program that would parse the input string(an email address)and print it in canonicalized format. It should have 3 parts separated by ',' as follows: Int,Int,String   The first two integer parts represent the indexes of the first and last character of substring that the program should extract. 
For example, let's say I type in the following as the input: 0,6,alex.da@yahoo.com  => The output should become => alex.da
Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Labs02 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("enter your Email:");
    String response = stdIn.nextLine(); 

    String first=response.substring(0,1);
    int second=response.indexOf(response.charAt(2));
    System.out.println(response.substring(response.indexOf(response.substring(0, 1))+4));    
    } //This is where I get stuck!
```

Comment: Removed the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the whole string using `,` and then parse starting two string to get positions and apply `String#subString` on third string like below,

```
String response = stdIn.nextLine(); 
String arr[] = response.split(","); // this will make three strings as "0" , "6", "alex.da@yahoo.com"
int first=Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
int second=Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
System.out.println(arr[2].substring(first, second + 1);
```

Comment: @sarah this approach is more safe, use this

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to separate the input string into its constructing parts, by using a the comma as a separator:

```
List<String> paramaters = Arrays.asList(response.split(","));
```

Then you need to extract the substrings as per your requirement:

```
String first = response.substring(Integer.parseInt(paramaters[0]),Integer.parseInt(parameters[1]));
```

the variable first would then hold your substring.

Comment: `get(int index)` method is used to random access in `List`.

Comment: right my bad, i was just typing in an editor, no ide to point that out. but would work too.